# draw2d and gef classes in windowbuilder implementation

Tags: eclipse-gef, windowbuilder, draw2d

I'm browsing the source code of windowbuilder. In the [org.eclipse.wb.core](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.windowbuilder/trunk/org.eclipse.wb.core/) plug-in, beside the [src](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.windowbuilder/trunk/org.eclipse.wb.core/src/) folder, there exists [src-draw2d](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.windowbuilder/trunk/org.eclipse.wb.core/src-draw2d/) and [src-gef](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.windowbuilder/trunk/org.eclipse.wb.core/src-gef/) folders which contains an identical (or at least very similar) implementation of eclipse.gef and eclipse.gef.draw2d.

Why don't they just import these plugins but do this code duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the source code in those directories, you will find that it is NOT draw2d or GEF, but their own implementation of the same functionality in a more simple way. For example, the GEF abstract `Command` class has 11 methods and two constructors, while the "new" WB abstract `Command` has only one method: execute.

I think they probably did this because although GEF is incredible, it is also big and complex, so they decided to re-implement a watered down version of it.